# Is accounting haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, work

I am soon going to be starting a degree in accountancy. I have tried to research this topic many times but have not found a proper answer. As far as I am aware, the job of an accountant involves dealing with the calculations of riba (interest). I was wondering is there any form of halal accounting? Or if I was to change my degree which degree would be acceptable but worth the £9000 each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly speaking, it would not be permissible if your job is related to the haram issue of Riba. Consequently you must ignore it if you are looking for a halal income and practice. But regarding the second part of your inquiry as you asked:

> Or if I was to change my degree which degree would be acceptable but
>   worth the £9000 each year.

It is true that it would be more expensive to it, but you’re definitely agree with me that having halal income and halal jobs would be so better for you if you indeed intend to do the orders of Islam. Besides, I strongly believe that Allah will compensate such disadvantages if you ignore a sin for the sake of Allah. Moreover, you can work in another fields or at least endeavor to field a related job with your degree which is not related to riba. And don't forget that rarely individuals have to make a very important decision in their life which can make their Akherah. Finally, in all probability you’ll make a true decision as you look a religious person. Good luck.

**Reference and more info.**

[http://islamquest.net/ ___ Farsi (Persian)](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa6987)

[http://islamquest.net/ ___ Indonesia](http://islamquest.net/id/archive/question/fa6987)

[http://islamquest.net/ ___ Melayu](http://islamquest.net/ms/archive/question/fa6987)